# Comma separated using string.Join with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I used string.Join in lambda expression to form comma seperated values

I achieved it using the following code:

```
    var viewData = queue.Select(items => new companyQueueWithSegInfo()
{
 segmentName = string.Join(",", items.Select(i => i.seginfo.Trim()));

                                  }).AsQueryable()

}
```

The output for this will be :

```
AB ,CD
```

But I need output as

```
AB, CD
```

I tried like this:

```
string.Join(" ,",items.Select(i => i.segminfo)).Replace(",", ", ").Replace(" ,","")
```

Can anyone help me with this?
 but it didn't work.

Comment: Join them with ", " and use Trim() on the result of the linq query

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `seginfo` is a `string`, how about [`Trim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) them first and then then join with `", "` ?

```
string.Join(", ", items.Select(i => i.seginfo.Trim()));
```

Also you should check your item is `null` or not for prevent NRE like;

```
string.Join(", ", list.Where(s => s != null).Select(i => i.Trim()))
```

or can use [`IsNullOrEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as others mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried using Trim but I am getting null reference exception while using it

Comment: @Priya: Calling Trim() on an empty string will result in an empty string. Calling Trim() on null will throw NullReferenceException

Comment: @Priya Do you have `null` values? What is your `items` exactly? Can you please show this collection and how it's structured in your question?

Comment: @Priya:- You can first try to check your string like this: `string.Join(", ", items.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
                      .Select(i => i.seginfo.Trim()));`

Comment: var viewData = queue.Select(items => new companyQueueWithSegInfo()
{
 segmentName = string.Join(", ", items.Select(i => i.seginfo.Trim()));
                                  
                                  }).AsQueryable()
                                
}


Like this I am using it @Soner

Comment: @Priya:- Try this: `var viewData = queue.Select(items => new companyQueueWithSegInfo() { segmentName = string.Join(", ", items.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).Select(i => i.seginfo.Trim())); }).AsQueryable() } `

Comment: @RahulTripathi

!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x) is not accepting in my context

Comment: @Priya Can you please update your question structure with `companyQueueWithSegInfo`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Trim()` for removing all leading and trailing white-space characters. And then just change `","` to `", "`:

```
var result = string.Join(", ", items.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
                                   .Select(i => i.seginfo.Trim()));
```

Be sure to check if the string is empty or null also as I did.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using [Trim()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ie, you need to join them with `", "` and then use the Trim():

```
string.Join(", ",items.Select(i => i.seginfo.Trim()))
```

To handle NULL condition of string try this:

```
string.Join(", ", items.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
                      .Select(i => i.seginfo.Trim()));
```